# Tkinter: how to make functions in after() work with variable objects?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to learn how to make code run continuously in tkinter.

My aim for testing is just to get a label to change colour every 2 seconds regardless of input.

I understand I can use the following format (with `lbl` initialised as a Label)

```
def switch():
    if lbl.cget('bg') == 'blue':
        lbl.config(bg='black')
    else:
        lbl.config(bg='blue')
    lbl.after(2000, switch)
```

This works fine. However, I want to be able to call `switch` for any label rather than just `lbl` specifically.

If I try the below I immediately get a recursion depth error

```
def switch(i):
    if i.cget('bg') == 'blue':
        i.config(bg='black')
    else:
        i.config(bg='blue')
    i.after(2000, switch(i))
 
lbl.after(2000, switch(lbl))
```

I'm not sure why this is a the case, or what I could do to get round it so any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: You need a `lambda` statement. Try `lambda: switch(i)` instead of just `switch(i)`. Similar to/duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/16775594).

Comment: That makes so much sense. Just so I have it right then: After() requires the name of a function to be called by itself. Prefixing the function I want to call with lambda: effectively wraps the full function in a single name that after() can recognise?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin: you don't _need_ lamda, it's just one possible solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley I hadn't heard of any other solutions until I saw your answer. I'll remember in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass positional arguments to after. To run `switch(i)` after 2 seconds you can call `after` like this, adding the positional arguments after the function:

```
i.after(2000, switch, i)
```

Likewise, to run `switch(lbl)` do this:

```
lbl.after(2000, switch, lbl)
```